# Get reference to nested control's sub control?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

- MainWindow.xaml has view model MainWindowViewModel.
- MainWindow.xaml has a nested User Control called
  CustomBrowserControl.xaml
- CustomBrowserControl.xaml has a named element webBrowser.
- MainWindowViewModel has a command that needs a reference to
  webBrowser.

  How do I pass the reference?

---

**The Solution I Came Up With**

Based on EthicalLogics and sa_ddam213's responses, yes, in the code behind of my MainWindow, if I named the user control (in the xaml, add the attribute x:Name="something"), I could then reference the user control object.  I could then pass that reference to the MainWindowViewModel.  This is also apparently bad practice, because it breaks MVVM.

*So what I did instead*

In my user control, I created two new depdency properties as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TakePictureCommand = DependencyProperty.Register("TakePicture", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BrowserControl));
    public ICommand TakePicture 
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(TakePictureCommand); }
        set { SetValue(TakePictureCommand, value); }
    }
```

Now in my MainWindow.xaml, I placed a button.  I was able to bind the button to the TakePicture command by using the following xaml:

```
<Window>
    <Button Content="Take Picture" Command="{Binding ElementName=browserControl, Path=DataContext.TakePicture}"  FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" ...>
    <myUserControls:BrowserControl x:Name="browserControl"   ... />
</Window>
```

This way I didn't need to pass a reference at all, and could just let the command / method in the user control, be invoked by the action on the main window.

Thank you so much to those who responded!!

Comment: Could you not just expose a public property for the webBrowser in your custom control? or can you not modify the custom control?

Comment: @sa_ddam213: I'm just learning WPF, and am trying to meet an insane deadline.  Right now, in my Application start, I instantiate my MainWindow's View Model object.  I then create a new MainWindow object, and inject the MainWindowViewModel into the MainWindow object, to become the MainWindow's data context.  I then call MainWindow.Show(), and because CustomBrowserControl is defined in MainWindow's xaml, it simply appears.

I don't know anything about dependency properties.

Comment: @sa_ddam213: Since posting this, I've figured out an alternative scenerio that could work, if I could figure out how to have a button on my MainWindow call a property of my CustomUserControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its a good practice to have references of Controls in ViewModel in MVVM . But you can create a property of Type WebBrowser Element in ViewModel and assign it like

```
((MainWindowViewModel)this.DataContext).WebBrowserProperty=CustomBrowserControl.webBrowser
```

I hope this will help.